# Capturando parâmetro de URL com jQuery

Tags: jquery

Atual estou capturando a URL da seguinte forma:

```
$(this).attr('href')
```

Vamos supor que a URL seja: http:/teste.com/login

Como faço para capturar somente o fim: /login

Answer (score 2):

Caso queira pegar somente a ultima "string" ('login') voce pode utilizar a propriedade split('/') que ira transformar a URL em um array baseado na '/' utilizada pelo mesmo, e a partir deste, vc pode pegar a ultima posicao deste array.

```
var URL = 'http://teste.com/login';
var URLArr = URL.split('/'); // ["http:", "teste.com", "login"]
var URLPath = URLArr[URLArr.length -1]; // "login"
```

Ou,

pode usar o replace

```
$(this).attr('href').replace(/^.*\/\/[^\/]+/, '');
```